# Resultados duplicados con INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

vengo con un problema con PHP y MYSQL.
Les cuento: Estoy creando como un sistema de seguidores, y lo había terminado e hice que funcionará, pero el código no era de lo mejor que digamos, porque... bueno, este era el código que yo tenía antes:

```
$followers = "SELECT * FROM seguidores WHERE userSeguido = '".$userName."'";
$resultFollowers = $conexion->query($followers);

if ($resultFollowers->num_rows > 0) {
   while ($dataFollowers = $resultFollowers->fetch_assoc()) {
    $followedname = $dataFollowers['userSeguido'];
    $followername = $dataFollowers['userSeguidor'];

    $dataseguidores = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE username = '".$followername."'";
    $resultdataseguidores = $conexion->query($dataseguidores);
    while ($dataFollowers_real = $resultdataseguidores->fetch_assoc()) {
        $usernameSeg = $dataFollowers_real['username'];
        $userprofilephotoSeg = $dataFollowers_real['userprofilephoto'];

        echo "<a href=\"$completeURL/user/$usernameSeg/bio\">
                <div class=\"follower\" style=\"background: url($completeURL/resize.php?r=$userprofilephotoSeg&w=200) center center / cover;\"></div>
            </a>";
    }
}
} else{
    echo "<p class=\"no-follow\">$userName no tiene seguidores</p>";
}
```

Funciona, si, pero vean ese pedazo de código, e hice otro que también funciona, pero me duplica los resultados.

Captura con el primer código:

[image: Primera captura]

Captura con el segundo código:

[image: Segunda captura]

Y bueno, no se porque pasa. Por ahí hice mal el código, pero me olvide de decirles que soy casi nuevo en esto de MYSQL y PHP.

Espero que me puedan ayudar! Si necesitan algo más, solo diganme.

El código que no funciona:

```
$seguidores = "SELECT * FROM 
            seguidores S 
        INNER JOIN 
            usuarios U ON S.userSeguido = '$userName'
        WHERE U.username != '$userName'";
$result = $conexion->query($seguidores);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $seguidor_imagen = $data['userprofilephoto'];
        $seguidor_nombre = $data['username'];

        echo "<a href=\"$completeURL/user/$seguidor_nombre/bio\">
                <div class=\"follower\" style=\"background: url($completeURL/resize.php?r=$seguidor_imagen&w=200) center center / cover;\"></div>
            </a>";
    }
} else{
    echo "<p class=\"no-follow\">Nada por acá...</p>";
}
```

Estructura de las tablas:

usuarios:

- userID (ID del usuario PK)
- username (Nombre del usuario)
- userprofilephoto (Foto de perfil del usuario)

seguidores:

- IDuserseguido (ID del usuario que se siguió)
- IDuserseguidor (ID user que siguió)
- userSeguido (Nombre del usuario que se siguió)
- userSeguidor (Nombre de usuario que siguió)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeramente creo que deberías eliminar algunos campos de las tablas que pueden ser redundantes. Tienes una tabla **usuarios** que contiene a todos los usuarios y luego una tabla **seguidores** con las relaciones entre ellos.

No es necesario tener el nombre del usuario nuevamente. Ademas *si el usuario cambia de nombre es un problema* ya que tendrías que actualizarlo en todos los seguidores y eso no es algo optimo.

```
usuarios:
    userID (ID del usuario PK)
    username (Nombre del usuario)
    userprofilephoto (Foto de perfil del usuario)

seguidores:
    IDuserseguido (ID del usuario seguido )
    IDuserseguidor (ID del usuario que esta siguiendo)
```

*IDuserseguido*  y *IDuserseguidor* deberían conformar una PK de forma que un usuario no pueda seguir dos veces al mismo usuario.

También es recomendable en la SQL usar solo los campos que deseas obtener y no usar "*" para traerlos todos. Si haces la consulta mas ligera obteniendo solo lo que se requiere es mas eficiente.

Con "*" estas obteniendo todos los campos de ambas tablas, pero solo usas dos de una de las dos tablas.

Una vez dicho esto. Si lo que quieres es sacar todos los nombres y foto de perfil de los usuarios que sigue un determinado usuario lo ideal seria conocer el ID de dicho usuario ya que es su PK y realizar una consulta como:

```
SELECT 
    U.username as username,
    U.userprofilephoto as userprofilephoto 
FROM 
    seguidores S INNER JOIN usuarios U ON U.userID = S.IDuserseguido 
WHERE 
    S.IDuserseguidor = $idUsuario
```

Si no tenemos el ID usuario podemos bien hacer la SQL antes y ponerlo o bien componerlo en la SQL anterior.

```
SELECT 
    U.username as username,
    U.userprofilephoto as userprofilephoto 
FROM 
    seguidores S INNER JOIN usuarios U ON U.userID = S.IDuserseguido 
WHERE 
    S.IDuserseguidor IN (SELECT userID FROM usuarios WHERE username='$username')
```

Comment: Si, de acá te respondo varias cosas.

Con el tema de "*", te doy toda la razón, porque es cierto.

Comment: Con el tema de tener los nombres de usuarios, es lo mismo, así que es verdad.
Ahora, con el tema de que la columna IDuserseguido e IDuserseguidor deberían ser PK, no haría falta, porque el botón que ejecuta el ajax para poder agregar el "seguidor", después cambia y al hacer clic de nuevo, no puede volver a seguir, si no que hace lo contrario.
Son dos funciones en un mismo botón.

Gracias por tu ayuda, ahora mismo voy a aplicar lo del "*".

Comment: El añadir ambas claves en la relación como PK te garantiza que tu base de datos es consistente. No hay posibilidad de duplicados. Asi mismo hace que este par sea un indice por lo que agilizas la búsqueda si creas una clave acorde. Siempre dependiendo del tipo de base de datos que uses en MySQL (MyISAM, InnoDB,...)

Answer (score 1):

1. Necesitaría las descripciones de las tablas, pero cuando juntas con join (en este caso, el "inner" sobra...) normalmente lo haces con las PK o alguna otra llave o índice, y no con valores como nombre o teléfono.
   El usuario seguido debería tener una referencia con la tabla principal usuarios usando la pk de la tabla usuarios. Con eso sería muy fácil (y muchísimo más rápido) referenciar ambos datos.
2. En el join usa índices. En la cláusula where puedes entonces buscar por nombre.
3. Si es posible, utiliza USING en vez de ON en el join, te ayudará con los duplicados.

Si no quieres invertir tiempo en mejorar tu sql, usa "SELECT DISTINCT" para deshacerte de los duplicados.

---

Sería entonces JOIN i usando los ids, más o menos así:

`Select * from usuarios join seguidores on userID = idseguidores where userseguido = '$username'`

Si tienes el `userid` del usuario logado, úsalo en la cláusula where, es mejor (con diferencia) que usar nombres.

Comment: Si, el INNER esta demás ahora que me lo dijiste.
Te muestro las tablas:

usuarios

Comment: Usuarios:
-userID (PK)
-username (Nombre del usuario)
-userprofilephoto (Foto de perfil del usuario)
Después tengo ochenta mil columnas más, pero esas no tienen nada que ver con esto

seguidores
-IDuserseguido (La id del usuario que se siguió)
-IDuserseguidor (La id del usuario que siguió al usuario)
- userSeguido (El nombre del usuario que se siguió)
- userSeguidor (El nombre del usuario que siguió al usuario)

Comment: No use las PK, porque en mi "sistema" no hay usuarios con el mismo nombre, por eso pensé en hacerlo así

Comment: @Alex, edita tu pregunta y añade allá la estructura de las tablas.

Comment: Las pk son para eso, identificar registros. Sin muy importantes en bases de datos. MySQL no hace buen uso de pk y fk (foreing Keys), por eso no me gusta mucho... Pero su sql es bastante estándar su poníamos esas deficiencias

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me funcionó perfectamente! Vamos a ver cuando suba el proyecto al servidor de prueba y lo pruebe con todos los usuarios que quieren probarlo!

https://i.gyazo.com/8c3c26b8e7d0ecdc38b6ae739905a7cc.png

Comment: (rehaciendo el comentario anterior, lo escribí con el móvil y quedó horrible...)

Las **PK** (_primary key_, o clave primaria) son para eso, identificar registros. Son muy importantes en bases de datos. **MySQL** no hace buen uso de PK y **FK** (_foreing keys_), por eso no me gusta mucho... Pero su **SQL** es bastante estándar, así supera esas deficiencias.